# Removing warnings of 64bit SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, 32bit-64bit

I guess everyone now will be using Xcode 5.1 and above. Once we add 64bit support to Valid Architecture, compiler throws warnings related to 64bit data types. I am working on app that is being supported from iOS6.0 if I change the data types that are of 64bit, will it work fine in 32bit devices? Because, changing the data types to 64bit will create compiler warnings for 32bit.. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to read the 64 bit transition guide for cocoa touch apps found at this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: It should not. And try to use datatype which will not get affected with 64bit or 32 bit change. Like use NSInteger instead of normal int and etc...

Answer (score 2):

If you are really worried about data type size then be explicit in your coding and use the standard types which will work regardless of the compiler.

```
uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t and uint64_t
int8_t,int16_t,int32_t and int64_t
```

The only place you really need to worry with 64 bit versus 32 bit is if you make assumptions about byte alignment of structures in your coding. However the solution to that is to also use the standard types.

for the likes of NSLog where you get lots of errors related to using NSInteger type types, you are supposed to cast them to what you want them to mean in the format statement. xcode usually will fix these for you.

Do you have any specific 32/64 examples you are worried about?

Comment: No specific examples, but i get hell lot of warnings asking 32bit to convert 64bit type. So, just wanted to make sure if I convert them according to what xcode suggests will not affect the app in any means while running it in 32bit devices..

Comment: Can you put in a couple of examples so I can see what kind of warning it is and in what situation? Most of the warnings I get are on NSLog which I let xcode fix. If the errors relate to mixing the use of short, int, long, long long etc, try not mixing int and long (use long) or move to using standard types. Going from 32bit to 64 is unlikely to lose you anything as its adding more range to numbers. As noted in answer, it is assuming structure alignment offsets, pointer sizes are the same and reading/writing binary data to servers from different devices on 32/64 bit where the real problems lie.

Comment: Examples like: 
1. warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'int - button tag int. 
2. warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' - [array count] assigning it to int
3. warning: values of type 'NSInteger' should not be used as format arguments; add an explicit cast to 'long' instead

Comment: Ok, makes sense and will not cause you problems as your code seems to work with the use of ints. You would be better to use the standard types or use long rather than int. The formatting raises the issue because it is probably coded to expect that NSInteger and NSUInteger may change size in the future, probably when 128bit comes in 8^). For these cast to (long) or (unsigned long). My advice though is use the standard types or use NSInteger and NSUInteger.